# WP CLI installs broken copies of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My local installs of wordpress in wamp appears not to work when done through wp-cli.

- The home page HTML has no styling and page elements are chaotically placed.
- The links are broken, some can be manually fixed by adding localhost/ in front of the string in the address bar.
- The admin page /wp-admin or wp-login.php is completely broken.

Running wp --info I see this information:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www> wp --info
OS:     Windows NT 10.0 build 16299 (Windows 10) AMD64
Shell:  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
PHP binary:     C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.exe
PHP version:    7.1.9
php.ini used:   C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:        phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI vendor dir:      phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:       C:\wamp64\www
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 1.5.0
```

This is the setup string I ran to install wordpress:

```
wp core download --path=example.com.com && cd example.com && wp config
 create --dbname=example.com --dbuser=root && wp db create && wp core 
install --url=http://example.com --title="WP Unit Tests" --admin_user=adm 
--admin_password=passwordhere --admin_email=myemail@gmail.com
```

It seemed to go smoothly in the command line (it didn't):

```
Creating directory 'C:\wamp64\www/example.com/'.
Downloading WordPress 4.9.5 (en_US)...
Using cached file 'C:\Users\Owner/.wp-cli/cache/core/wordpress-4.9.5-en_US.tar.gz'...
Success: WordPress downloaded.
Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.
Success: Database created.
Success: WordPress installed successfully.
```

Installs performed manually seem to work fine though.

I'm guessing one of the statements is wrong, or maybe a database permission area (not my forte. But with a root user?) These are just hunches though. Can anyone infer the issue based on this description?

Comment: Are you accessing the site over which url? localhost or example.com?

Comment: I am accessing via localhost/example.com  This produces the unstyled homepage (issue does not happen on my manual WP installs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else gets this, here was how I fixed it:

```
wp core install --url=http://example.com
```

should be:

```
wp core install --url=http://localhost/example.com
```